# How to save multiple row forms in laravel using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Hey guys I'm a bit confused with this. How do I input multi row forms in Laravel 5.5 using ajax? The idea is to add items and when adding items the Item number increments, then
I want to save this table in my database:
[image]

#### Here is my code for the blade with its script:

*pr-items.blade.php*

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Your main wrapper -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Add Items</h3></div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <form name="add_item" id="add_item" class="form-inline">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}


                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pr_form_number">PR Form Number: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pr_number" value="{{$pr_details}}" readonly required><br><br>
                      </div>

                      <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="tab_logic">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class='info'>
                                    <th style='width:10%;'>ITEM NO.</th>
                                    <th style='width:10%;'>QTY</th>
                                    <th style='width:10%;'>UNIT</th>
                                    <th style='width:30%;'>DESCRIPTION</th>
                                    <th style='width:10%;'>COST PER UNIT</th>
                                    <th style='width:10%;'>COST PER ITEM</th>
                                    <th style='width:10%;'>ACTION</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <thead>
                                <tr id="addr0">
                                    <td class="custom-tbl"><input class='form-control input-sm'style='width:100%;' type="text" value="1" id="pr_item0" name="pr_item[]" readonly required></td>
                                    <td class="custom-tbl"><input class='form-control input-sm' style='width:100%;' type="text" id="pr_qty0" oninput='multiply(0);' name="pr_qty[]"></td>
                                    <td class="custom-tbl"><input class='form-control input-sm' style='width:100%;' type="text" id="pr_unit0" name="pr_unit[]"></td>
                                    <td class="custom-tbl"><input class='form-control input-sm' style='width:100%;' type="text" id="pr_desc0" name="pr_desc[]"></td>
                                    <td><input class='form-control input-sm' style='width:100%;' type="text" id="pr_cpu0" oninput='multiply(0);' name="pr_cpu[]"></td>
                                    <td class="custom-tbl"><input class='estimated_cost form-control input-sm' id="pr_cpi0" style='width:100%;' type="text" name="pr_cpi[]" readonly></td>
                                    <td class="custom-tbl"><button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="dynamic_field">

                            <tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr class='info'>
                                    <td style='width:65%;text-align:right;padding:4px;' colspan='5'>GRAND TOTAL:</td>
                                    <td style='padding:0px;'>

                                            <input style='width:100%;' type='text' class='form-control input-sm' id='grand_total' name='grand_total' value='0' readonly required>

                                    </td>

                            </tfoot>

                        </table>
                      </div>


                      <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</div>



@endsection

@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function(){      
      var postURL = "<?php echo url('addmore'); ?>";
      var i=1;  


      $('#add').click(function(){
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_item'+i+'" class="form-control input-sm"style="width:100%;" type="text" value="'+i+'" name="pr_item[]" readonly required></td><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_qty'+i+'"class="form-control input-sm" style="width:100%;" type="text" oninput="multiply('+i+');" name="pr_qty[]"></td><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_unit'+i+'"class="form-control input-sm" style="width:100%;" type="text" name="pr_unit[]"></td><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_desc'+i+'" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:100%;" type="text" name="pr_desc[]"></td><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_cpu'+i+'" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:100%;" type="text" oninput="multiply('+i+');" name="pr_cpu[]"></td><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_cpi'+i+'" class="estimated_cost form-control input-sm" style="width:100%;" type="text" name="pr_cpi[]" readonly></td><td class="custom-tbl"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn_remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></td></tr>');  
      });  


      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });

      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      });


      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"{{route('pr.items.add')}}",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_item').serialize(),
                type:'json',

           });  
      });  

    });




</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function multiply(id)
        {
            var total1=parseFloat($('#pr_qty'+id).val())*parseFloat($('#pr_cpu'+id).val());
            $("input[id=pr_cpi" + id + "]").val(total1);
            grandTotal();
        }
function grandTotal()
        {
            var items = document.getElementsByClassName("estimated_cost");
            var itemCount = items.length;
            var total = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
            {
                total = total +  parseFloat(items[i].value);
            }
            document.getElementById('grand_total').value = total;
        }
</script>

@endsection
```

#### And here is a part of my controller for storing its data

*PurchaseRequestItemController.php*

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //


        $rules = [];


        foreach($request->input('pr_item') as $key => $value) {
            $rules["pr_item.{$key}"] = 'required';
            $rules["pr_qty.{$key}"] = 'required';
            $rules["pr_unit.{$key}"] = 'required';
            $rules["pr_desc.{$key}"] = 'required';
            $rules["pr_cpu.{$key}"] = 'required';
            $rules["pr_cpi.{$key}"] = 'required';
        }


        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);


        if ($validator->passes()) {


            foreach($request->input('pr_item') as $key => $value) {

                $Record=new PurchaseRequestItemModel;

                $Record->pr_form_number = $request->get('pr_number');
                $Record->item_no = $request->get('pr_item');
                $Record->pr_qty = $request->get('pr_qty');
                $Record->pr_unit = $request->get('pr_unit');
                $Record->pr_description =$request->get('pr_desc') ; 
                $Record->pr_cost_per_unit =$request->get('pr_cpu') ;
                $Record->pr_estimated_cost =$request->get('pr_cpi') ;

                $Record->save();
            }


            return response()->json(['success'=>'done']);
        }else{

        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);}




    }
```

***edit: Also my form is an array.***
How do I also make sure that after saving I can view the table as it is?

It also returns this error when I save
[image]

Comment: what was the issue in current code?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama It does not save. It returns an error. Also I am looking for a more efficient way of doing hte process of saving multiple forms

Comment: so what was the error?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama it's up there, edited my question. :)

Comment: error 500 is server error.

Comment: @guradio yes but I don't know what's wrong with the controller? can ayou help me guys?

Comment: error check in preview in network when ajax call

Comment: @BhargavChudasama it sayas: _Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `pr_items` (`pr_form_number`, `item_no`, `pr_qty`, `pr_unit`, `pr_description`, `pr_cost_per_unit`, `pr_estimated_cost`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (PR-ICT-2018-01-0000, 1, 12, pcs, asasa, 120, 1440, 2018-10-23 13:57:58, 2018-10-23 13:57:58))"_

Comment: its given any line number or run this query in your mysql and check manually where is error

Comment: use `dd($request->all())` and show the output

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta here's the output: https://imgur.com/a/iG1jIhj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example $request->get('pr_number'); this is an array so can't get the specific value without defining the index. You have to define the index of array. Try this. Hope it will work.

```
foreach($request->input('pr_item') as $key => $value) {

            $Record=new PurchaseRequestItemModel;

            $Record->pr_form_number = $request->get('pr_number')[$key];
            $Record->item_no = $request->get('pr_item')[$key];
            $Record->pr_qty = $request->get('pr_qty')[$key];
            $Record->pr_unit = $request->get('pr_unit')[$key];
            $Record->pr_description =$request->get('pr_desc')[$key]; 
            $Record->pr_cost_per_unit =$request->get('pr_cpu')[$key];
            $Record->pr_estimated_cost =$request->get('pr_cpi')[$key];

            $Record->save();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
$pr_item=$request->get('pr_item');
$pr_qty=$request->get('pr_qty');
$pr_unit=$request->get('pr_unit');
$pr_desc=$request->get('pr_desc');
$pr_cpu=$request->get('pr_cpu');
$pr_cpi=$request->get('pr_cpi');
for($i = 0; $i < count($request->get('pr_item')); $i++)
            $Record=new PurchaseRequestItemModel;
            $Record->pr_form_number =    $request->get('pr_number');
            $Record->item_no =           $pr_item[$i];
            $Record->pr_qty =            $pr_qty[$i];
            $Record->pr_unit =           $pr_unit[$i];
            $Record->pr_description =    $pr_desc[$i]; 
            $Record->pr_cost_per_unit =  $pr_cpu[$i];
            $Record->pr_estimated_cost = $pr_cpi[$i];
            $Record->save();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Use $request->all() and fetch values as below it will work.

 foreach( $request->all() as $value ) {
    $record = new PurchaseRequestItemModel;
    $record->pr_form_number = $value['pr_number'];
    $record->item_no = $value['pr_item'];
    $record->pr_qty = $value['pr_qty'];
    $record->pr_unit = $value['pr_unit'];
    $record->pr_description =$value['pr_desc')];
    $record->pr_cost_per_unit =$value['pr_cpu')];
    $record->pr_estimated_cost =$value['pr_cpi')];
    $record->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
foreach($request->input('pr_item') as $key => $value) 
{
     $item = new PurchaseRequestItemModel;
     $item ->pr_form_number = $request->get('pr_number')[$key];
     $item ->item_no = $request->get('pr_item')[$key];
     // mention other fields here
     $item ->save();
}
```